# Moving subsets of bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am dealing with a bipartite graph $G = (L\cup R, E)$. The left and right sets are both assumed to be regular with degrees $d_L$ and $d_R$. Assume $|L| > |R|$ and hence $d_L < d_R$.

Let $S \subset L$ and $\Gamma(S) \subset R$ be its neighborhood.
Any vertex in $\Gamma(\Gamma(S)) \subseteq L$ is said to be in the boundary $\beta_S$ of $\Gamma(S)$.

I would now like to 'move' this set S. Let $u \in \beta_S$ and $v \in S$. I can perform the mapping $S \rightarrow S' := (S \cup u) \setminus v$.

The catch is that I'd like $|\Gamma(S)|$, the size of the boundary, to remain the same. How many ways can I do so?

At the very least, is there some way to lower bound the size of $|\Gamma(S)|$?

Comment: Do you want $|\Gamma(S)|$ (the size of the *neighborhood*) to stay the same or the size of the boundary to stay the same, or both? I am guessing you just mean the neighborhood right?

Comment: Yes, I do mean the size of the neighborhood. I'd like $|\Gamma(S)|$ to stay the same

Comment: @WiFO215 : It seems there is a typo somewhere because you say "$|\Gamma(S)|$, the size of the boundary" but earlier you define "boundary" to be $\Gamma(\Gamma(S))$ and you say that $\Gamma(S)$ is the "neighborhood".

Comment: @WiFO215: seconding Timothy Chow's comment, and suggesting an improvement of the wording of the OP: would you please make the definition of "boundary" absolutely unambiguous by writing "For any $S\subseteq L$, let the "boundary of $S$ in $G$", be $\beta_S:=\Gamma(\Gamma(S))\subseteq L$." And: clarify *what* you want to "remain the same". Is it $\lvert\beta_S\rvert$? Ist it $\Gamma(S)$? (The latter, which is how it is currently written, seems not to make much sense to me. I think only after such corrections will people think about your question.

Comment: Hi Timothy, Peter

Sorry for the confusing wording. I meant to say that $\Gamma(\cdot)$ meant the boundary of the set contained in parentheses.

$\beta_S$ ought to have been called the boundary of $\Gamma(S)$ and not the boundary of $S$. $\Gamma(S)$ is the boundary of $S$. I've edited the original post to reflect this.

In performing this transformation, I would like to lower bound $|\Gamma(S)|$, the boundary of $S$.